# How do you check if an Accessibility service stopped working?

Tags: java, android

Here's a method to check if an accessibility service is enabled:

```
public boolean isAccessServiceEnabled(Context context) {
    String prefString = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
    if (prefString != null)
        return prefString.contains(context.getPackageName() + "/" + MyAccessibilityService.class.getName());
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the accessibility service randomly stops working but the above method will return that it's enabled. So is there a way to detect if an accessibility service is not functioning?